# Combine columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with these columns:

- module varchar
- cycle Date
- autoNum int

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [id]
      ,[module]
      ,FORMAT([cycle],'yyyyMM') as cycle
      ,RIGHT('000000'+CAST([autoNum] as varchar(5)),5) as autoNum
     
  FROM [Inventory].[dbo].[tbl_invoiceGIN]
```

| id | module | cycle | autoNum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | IN | 2301 | 00001 |
| 2 | OUT | 2301 | 00001 |

I want to combine two of the columns to make a new column like this:

| id | module | cycle | autoNum | DocNo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | IN | 2301 | 00001 | IN2301-00001 |
| 2 | OUT | 2301 | 00001 | OUT2301-00001 |

How can I do it?

Comment: Feels like SQL Server, so why would you tag MySQL an PostgreSQL ?

Comment: Seems like you've confused rows and columns.

Comment: I am change tag already sorry my mistake

Comment: Since you are already taking the hit for format(), you might as will use format([autoNum] ,'00000')

Comment: SELECT ... x.Col1 + x.Col2 FROM (Your Query) x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Repeat the expressions:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [id]
    ,[module]
    ,FORMAT([cycle],'yyyyMM') as cycle
    ,RIGHT('000000'+CAST([autoNum] as varchar(5)),5) as autoNum
    ,FORMAT([cycle],'yyyyMM') + '-' +  RIGHT('000000'+CAST([autoNum] as varchar(5)),5) As DocNo    
FROM [Inventory].[dbo].[tbl_invoiceGIN]
```

Or use nested SELECT statements:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 id, [module], cycle, autoNum, cycle+'-'+autoNum As DocNo
FROM (
    SELECT [id]
        ,[module]
        ,FORMAT([cycle],'yyyyMM') as cycle
        ,RIGHT('000000'+CAST([autoNum] as varchar(5)),5) as autoNum  
    FROM [Inventory].[dbo].[tbl_invoiceGIN]
) i
```

Comment: you save me thank Somuch brother

Comment: @SoPhea: ff this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.